# Javascript error if statement is not proceeding forward after function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, tabs, event-handling, javascript-objects

I have created a tabs dropdown module using javascript & it is working fine

```
const service = document.querySelectorAll('[data-step-id="service"]');

const category = service[1].querySelectorAll('.service_category');
const sedan = category[0];
const suv = category[1];
const others = category[2];
const monthlypackages = category[3];

const servicecard = service[1].querySelectorAll('.service_card');

// onclick Sedan Category The first 4 service cards from(0-3) will show/hide
sedan.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if (servicecard[i].classList.contains('h-hide')){
            servicecard[i].classList.remove('h-hide');
        }
        else {servicecard[i].classList.add('h-hide');}
    }
});

// onclick SUV Category The 4 service cards from(4-7) will show/hide
suv.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var i = 4; i < 8; i++){
        if (servicecard[i].classList.contains('h-hide')){
            servicecard[i].classList.remove('h-hide');
        }
        else {servicecard[i].classList.add('h-hide');}
    }
});

// onclick Others Category The 3 service cards from(8-10) will show/hide
others.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var i = 8; i < 11; i++){
        if (servicecard[i].classList.contains('h-hide')){
            servicecard[i].classList.remove('h-hide');
        }
        else {servicecard[i].classList.add('h-hide');}
    }
});

// onclick monthlypackages Category The last 3 service cards from(11-13) will show/hide
monthlypackages.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var i = 11; i < servicecard.length; i++){
        if (servicecard[i].classList.contains('h-hide')){
            servicecard[i].classList.remove('h-hide');
        }
        else {servicecard[i].classList.add('h-hide');}
    }
});
```

> **To this I want to add is only one at a time should be opened**

I am trying to do like this but not working on all scenarios

1. All tabs should not be opened at the same time like sedan category is visible others should not be visible. - **This is working only for the first time**
2. All category tabs should toggle show/hide - **This is Not working**

   ```
   const sedanfirstchild = servicecard[0];
   const suvfirstchild = servicecard[4];
   const otherfirstchild = servicecard[8];
   const monthlypackagesfirstchild = servicecard[11]; 
   function sedannone() {
       if (sedanfirstchild.classList.contains('h-hide')){
           console.log('Sedan is not Visible');
       }
       else {
           sedan.click();
       }
   }
   function suvnone() {
       if (suvfirstchild.classList.contains('h-hide')){
           console.log('SUV is not Visible');
       }
       else {
           suv.click();
       }
   }
   function othersnone() {
       if (otherfirstchild.classList.contains('h-hide')){
           console.log('Others is not Visible');
       }
       else {
           others.click();
       }
   }
   function monthlypackagesnone() {
       if (monthlypackagesfirstchild.classList.contains('h-hide')){
           console.log('monthly packages is not Visible');
       }
       else {
           monthlypackages.click();
       }
   }
   // onclick Sedan Category The first 4 service cards from(0-3) will show/hide
   sedan.addEventListener('click', function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
           if (servicecard[i].classList.contains('h-hide')){
               suvnone();
               othersnone();
               monthlypackagesnone();
               servicecard[i].classList.remove('h-hide');
           }
           else {servicecard[i].classList.add('h-hide');}
       }
   });

   // onclick SUV Category The 4 service cards from(4-7) will show/hide
   suv.addEventListener('click', function() {
       for (var i = 4; i < 8; i++){
           if (servicecard[i].classList.contains('h-hide')){
               sedannone();
               othersnone();
               monthlypackagesnone();
               servicecard[i].classList.remove('h-hide');
           }
           else {servicecard[i].classList.add('h-hide');}
       }
   });

   // onclick Others Category The 3 service cards from(8-10) will show/hide
   others.addEventListener('click', function() {
       for (var i = 8; i < 11; i++){
           if (servicecard[i].classList.contains('h-hide')){
               sedannone();
               suvsnone();
               monthlypackagesnone();
               servicecard[i].classList.remove('h-hide');
           }
           else {servicecard[i].classList.add('h-hide');}
       }
   });

   // onclick monthlypackages Category The last 3 service cards from(11-13) will show/hide
   monthlypackages.addEventListener('click', function() {
       for (var i = 11; i < servicecard.length; i++){
           if (servicecard[i].classList.contains('h-hide')){
               sedannone();
               suvnone();
               othersnone();
               servicecard[i].classList.remove('h-hide');
           }
           else {servicecard[i].classList.add('h-hide');}
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: JS Fiddle - V1 https://jsfiddle.net/y36eazvs/4/
JS Fiddle - V2 https://jsfiddle.net/s8wd7Lo9/3/